# Bottling in Aluminum Coors Light Pint Cans?

Tags: bottling

I have several aluminum Coors Light Pint cans with screw-top caps. I haven't tried to bottle with them yet. Has anyone else successfully bottled in these cans?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just give it a try?

Comment: Do a test using any carbonated soda to confirm that it holds pressure, but it should since it was used for that purpose...  even sparkling water bottle caps work according to my tests.

Comment: How are you planning to sanitize them?